# Why my WPF app not showing publisher name in task manager's Start Up

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, task

I am actually unable to verify that why my wpf app is not showing its publisher name when I set it as startup app in task manager from my app installer. I have tried different solutions using Orca and using Assembly info tab but nothing is working for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Fill in the company in the assembly information,then you can see the publisher under the startup page of the task manager

[image]